# Can sqlite load individual tables from individual files?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I've heard that SQLite can do this (to avoid synchronicity issues in heavy traffic scenarios) is this true?  If so how would I do this with PDO in PHP?

Answer (score 6):

Would you be looking for the ATTACH and DETACH sqlite commands? You can call these with a query to any SQLite PDO object.

The commands allow you to attach a separate database file to the current session. An example would be:

```
$connection->query('ATTACH DATABASE blog_entries.sqlite AS BlogEntries;');
```

You can then refer to the tables located in the attached database by their name (eg: `SELECT * FROM entries`) if there is no duplicate tables. If there is a conflict then they need to be namespaced with the database alias (eg: `SELECT * FROM BlogEntries.entries`)

Reference: [SQLite Manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can open a DB in memory (I believe the DSN for PDO is **sqlite:memory:**) and attach the different databases.